# How to delete items from array list

Tags: java, android, arrays

I have array of strings like `{item1,item2,item3,...,itemN}`. I want to delete specific element from array. How can i do? Simplest way..

```
String s="How to delete items from list";

String[] result = s.split("\\s");
```

Now, I want to remove "delete" and "items" from `array` "result".

Answer (score 1):

Use a `List<String>` as below.

```
            List<String> myList = Arrays.asList(new LinkedList<String>(Arrays.asList(arrayname));
);
                    myList.remove(index);
```

Comment: .UnsupportedOperationException

Comment: I have edited my code to avoid this exception

Answer (score 0):

Deletion in `Array` is not possible. You can initialize the position with null value but size will not be reduced.

```
String s="How to delete items from list";
String[] result = s.split("\s");      
result[2] = null;
```

Comment: any reason why answer is downvoted?

Comment: i want shift the place of array as well. Means at resutl[2] i want "from"

Answer (score 0):

```
List<String> arr = new LinkedList<String>(Arrays.asList(result));
arr.remove(2);
arr.remove(3);

System.out.println(arr.toArray(new String[0]));
```